How to create a vector of 2 elements?
For a function I want to utilize the documentation states that I need to create a vector of 2 elements.
library("dplyr")

df <- data.frame(
  Genus = c("Panthera", "Quercus", "Rosa", "Acer", "Canis"),
  Species = c("leo", "robur", "rubiginosa", "saccharum", "lupus"),
  Common_Name = c("Lion", "English Oak", "Rusty Rose", "Sugar Maple", "Wolf"),
  Latitude = c(1.2921, 51.5074, 48.8566, 45.4215, 37.7749),
  Longitude = c(36.8219, -0.1278, 2.3522, -75.6972, -122.4194)
)



I tried:
latlong<- c(df$Latitude,df$Longitude)

However that just gives me one long vector and I need vector pairs.
I also tried:
latlong<- c("Latitude","Longitude")

however that just gives me a string of 2 characters.
Its probably an easy solution but I don't know how to go about accomplishing it.
Edit:
The documentation can be found here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/divvy/divvy.pdf
The function I am specifically looking at is bandit.
In terms of "a vector of two elements", I'm unsure what the output should look like those are just the exact words in the documentation.
I just tried:
df[,c("Latitude", "Longitude")]

which I thought was what I needed but it returned the following error:
Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
In which I attempted to use as.vector() and recieved the same error

It's not clear what's meant by vector of 2 elements (probably not 1:2, which is a vector with two elements). Maybe you mean df[,c("Latitude", "Longitude")]. If not please provide a minimal example of the desired output.

To reduce ambiguity, could you share which documentation of what function is looking for what?

The xy param is described in the linked documentation as:

A vector of two elements, specifying the name or numeric position of columns
in dat containing coordinates, e.g. longitude and latitude

One example in the documentation is:
...
obs <- data.frame(x, y, sp)
...
sdSumry(obs, xy = c('x','y'), ...

Given the names in your frame, I suspect that:
xy = c('Latitude', 'Longitude')

is what's expected here.
